# I have looked for some time but i still don't understand self in python

Tags: python, self

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python ‘self’ explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

I have looked for some time but i still don't understand  self in python

```
def cut(self, cats, dogs):
     self.cats = cats
     self.dogs = dogs
     print cats, dogs
cut(1,5)
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it? What it's used for? Why it's used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained

Comment: There's [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/1079354) and [this page from the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks).  You could call `self` `this`, if it helps you understand it a bit better (it's pretty similar).

Comment: @Makoto: ...but don't, since that will reduce the readability of your code (to other Python users, at least).

Comment: Of course not.  That's exactly what the docs say! :P

Comment: You get down votes for asking a question you don't know the answer to.  Don't do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is just a local variable. You could name it anything you like, but the convention is to name it `self`. When a function is invoked as a method, i.e. on an actual object, Python will pass a reference to the object as the first argument. This is what `self` points to.

`obj.method(param)` is actually just syntactic sugar for `ObjType.method(obj, param)`. So that's where the parameter comes from.